# Is PageContext shared between Sessions or Requests in JAVA?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

In my custom tag library I'm using the pageContext: is it shared between requests of different HttpSession? Is it shared between requests of the same HttpSession? Is it created for every Requests that access the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PageContext` is not shared between `HttpRequest` instances. It's scope is narrower than the one of a request and is bound to a single JSP page execution. There can be few page contexts within a request (via include or forward) and it contains handles to request and session (among other) objects